# Why converting datetime to pendulum returns values off by some seconds in python

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow I have `'start_date': datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1),` in `default_args.py` while testing it using unittest as below

```
start_date = dag.default_args.get('start_date')
self.assertEqual(start_date, pendulum.now() - timedelta(days=1))
```

I get AssertionError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.assertEqual(start_date, pendulum.now().subtract(days=1))
AssertionError: <Pendulum [2019-11-04T02:39:33.277268+00:00]> != <Pendulum [2019-11-04T02:39:38.028295+00:00]>
```

I can see the response is off by few seconds and thus it assertion fails. However, I am not sure why it is off and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably takes a couple of seconds for things to make it from `default_args.py` to where your test code gets run.

You'll have to assert whether the dates are close enough, i.e. something like this. (I haven't used `pendulum`; no idea whether its timedeltas have `total_seconds()` like `datetime.timedelta`s do.)

```py
ALLOWED_LEEWAY = 5

# ...

start_date = dag.default_args.get('start_date')
expected_start_date = pendulum.now() - timedelta(days=1)
assert abs((expected_start_date - start_date).total_seconds()) <= ALLOWED_LEEWAY
```